# how to get text of the neighbour textviews on some other textview's onclick event in dynamic table?

Tags: android, tags, textview

i have textviews in table layout like this

```
----------------
|txt1|txt2|txt3|
----------------
|txt4|txt5|txt6|
----------------
|txt7|txt8|txt9|
----------------
|txt1|txt2|txt3|
----------------
|txt4|txt5|txt6|
----------------
|txt7|txt8|txt9|
```

and so on and on and on0

in this manner i am adding textviews again and again in for loop in the table layout acc to the data which is coming dynamically...

on txt7 click listener event i can get the text of the txt7 like this

```
((TextView)v).getText().toString();
```

now i need text of txt8 and txt9 text on txt7 click event

some body suggested me to do this by tagging textview

```
TextView uniqueTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.unique_id);
TextView neighbourView = new TextView();
neighbourView.setTag(uniqueTextView);

public void onTextViewClick(TextView view) {
TextView uniqueTextView = (TextView)view.getTag();
String text = uniqueTextView.getText().toString();   }
```

but this for one textview... how can i get text of both textview(txt8+txt9) on txt7 click listener.... plus i need text from txt7 also....

if it is not clear then you can comment....

this is dynamic table which i am creating

```
TableRow tr1 = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
TextView txt1=new TextView(this);
TextView txt2=new TextView(this);
TextView txt3=new TextView(this);
txt1.setText("Data1);
txt2.setText("Data2);
txt3.setText("Data3);
txt1.setTag(1, txt2.getText().toString());
txt1.setTag(2, txt3.getText().toString());

txt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
    try
    {
          Log.i("asdasd","Yahoo");
              Toast(((TextView)v).getTag(1).toString());
              Toast(((TextView)v).getTag(2).toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         Log.i("Error came while getting tag of txt1", e.getMessage());
        Toast("unable to bind tag");
        }
     }
});

tr1.addView(txt1);
tr1.addView(txt2);
tr1.addView(txt3);
TableLayout tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams));
```

as i cant set txt1 in place of ((TextView)v) because it will always give text of the last tablerow's txt1

```
04-20 12:42:39.236: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:136)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at com.connection.demotable$1.onClick(demotable.java:431)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-20 12:42:39.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(522):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how to gettag of the dynamically generated textview. If i am applying this... --((TextView)v).getTag().toString();--... then it is giving error.... But if i apply this --txt7.getTag().toString());-- then it is tag....

Comment: this is the error i am getting

Comment: see you are doing `getTag()` instead of `getTag(1)` or `getTag(2)`

Comment: now this error is coming java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.

Comment: oops it seems the ids need to be present as resources. `The specified key should be an id declared in the resources of the application to ensure it is unique (see the ID resource type). Keys identified as belonging to the Android framework or not associated with any package will cause an IllegalArgumentException to be thrown.` Running out of space, see the next comment

Comment: Instead try this code, `String[] otherTxts = new String[] {txt2.getText().toString(), txt3.getText().toString()}; txt1.setTag(otherTxts);` in onClick use getTag() cast the object to String array and voila there are your strings

Comment: ok but still i am going to get the text of the last tablerow's textview on any textview click event in the tablelayout.... i want something like ((TextView)v).getTag().toString() to get the tag of any textview i click in tablelayout... which is not working

Comment: actually error is from my side because i am taking static textview like txt1, txt2,,, i should have taken textview like this txt[1], txt[2].... then it wouldn't have been that bigger problem... by the away thanx for the reply

Comment: I think you must be iterating the piece of code which you posted above in a for loop. Assuming this try this out `txt1.setTag(new String[] {txt2.getText().toString(), txt3.getText().toString()});` and in the onClick method try this `public void onClick(View v) {
    try
    {
          Log.i("asdasd","Yahoo");
              Toast(((TextView)v).getTag(1).toString());
              Toast(((TextView)v).getTag(2).toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         Log.i("Error came while getting tag of txt1", e.getMessage());
        Toast("unable to bind tag");
        }
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the example code you posted try this

```
txt7.setTag(1, txt8);
txt7.setTag(2, txt9);

public void onTextViewClick(TextView view) {
TextView txt8 = (TextView)view.getTag(1);
TextView txt9 = (TextView)view.getTag(2);   }
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try [setTag (int key, Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [getTag(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29)

Comment: how to gettag of the dynamically generated textview

Comment: can you post your code where you dynamically generate the textviews ? It would be easier to point it out there

Comment: TableRow tr1 = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
    
TextView txt1=new TextView(this);

txt11.setText(strinarr[0]);
        
tr1.addView(txt1);
tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams));

Answer (score 1):

I have not used table layout yet. But you may can use like this

```
TableRow t =  (TableRow) v.getParent();
TextView t1 = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
TextView t2 = (TextView) t.getChildAt(1);
TextView t3 = (TextView) t.getChildAt(2);
```